# How do I update all rows of a postgres table sequentially, and run the query in parallel while avoiding deadlocks?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, plpgsql

First question here after years of reading answers, so apologies if I've got some things wrong!

I'm creating a very large image mosaic (e.g. a big image made of lots of small images) and I've got it working, but I'm struggling to work out how to assign the candidate images to the target locations in parallel.

I have two tables in a postgres database - `tiles` and `candidates`. Each contains 50,000 rows.

For each candidate, I want to assign it to the best target location (tile) that has not already been assigned a candidate.

My tables look like this:

```sql
create table candidates
(
    id            integer not null   primary key,
    lab_l         double precision,
    lab_a         double precision,
    lab_b         double precision,
    processing_by integer
);


create table tiles
(
    id           integer not null primary key,
    pos_x        integer,
    pos_y        integer,
    lab_l        double precision,
    lab_a        double precision,
    lab_b        double precision,
    candidate_id integer
);
```

To find the best tile for a candidate I'm using this function:

```sql
create or replace function update_candidates() RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE SQL
    PARALLEL SAFE
AS
$$
WITH updated_candidate AS (
    SELECT id, pg_advisory_xact_lock(id)
    FROM candidates
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM candidates
            FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
        LIMIT1
    )
)
UPDATE tiles
SET candidate_id = (SELECT id FROM updated_candidate)
WHERE tiles.id = (SELECT tile_id
                  FROM (select t.id                                        AS tile_id,
                               c.id                                        AS candidate_id,
                               delta_e_cie_2000(t.lab_l, t.lab_a, t.lab_b,
                                                c.lab_l, c.lab_a, c.lab_b) AS diff
                        FROM tiles t,
                             candidates c
                        WHERE c.id = (SELECT id FROM updated_candidate)
                          AND t.candidate_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY diff ASC
                        LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
                       ) AS ticid)
RETURNING id;
$$
;
```

Which uses the [`delta_e_cie_2000`](https://pgxn.org/dist/colors/doc/colors.html) function to calculate the color difference between candidate and each of the un-used tiles.

To assign all the candidates to tiles I'm using this function:

```sql
create or replace function update_all_tiles() RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    PARALLEL SAFE
AS
$$
DECLARE
    counter integer := 0;
    last_id integer := 1;
BEGIN
    WHILE last_id IS NOT NULL
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'Counter %', counter;
            counter := counter + 1;
            last_id := update_candidates();
            RAISE NOTICE 'Updated %', last_id;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN counter;
END
$$
;
```

Running `select update_all_tiles();` is working fine on a single thread. It's producing the correct output but it's pretty slow - it takes 20-30 minutes to update 50,000 tiles.

I'm running it on a machine with lots of cores and was hoping to use them all, or at least more than one.

However, if I run `select update_all_tiles()` in a second session the it runs for a while and then one of the processes outputs something along the lines of

```
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 2541 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1628083; blocked by process 1664.
Process 1664 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1628084; blocked by process 2541.
```

Ideally, I'd like the `update_all_tiles()` function itself to run in parallel so I could just call it once and it would use all the cores.

If that's not possible I'd like to be able to run the function in multiple sessions.

Is there a way I can do this while avoiding the `deadlock detected` error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I solved this specific issue like this

```sql
create or replace function assign_next_candidate() returns int
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    PARALLEL SAFE
as
$$
declare
    _candidate_id integer := 0;
    _tile_id      integer := 0;
begin
    --first we get a candidate, and lock it (using `FOR UPDATE`) so that no other process will pick it up
    -- and `SKIP LOCKED` so that we don't pick up one another process is using
    UPDATE candidates
    set processing_by = pg_backend_pid()
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT id
        from candidates
        where processing_by is null
            FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
        LIMIT 1
    )
    RETURNING id into _candidate_id;
    raise notice 'Candidate %', _candidate_id;

    -- now we get the least different tile that is not locked and update it, using the candidate_id from the previous query
    UPDATE tiles
    set candidate_id = _candidate_id
    WHERE id = (
        select t.id as tile_id
        from tiles t,
             candidates c
        where c.id = _candidate_id
          and t.candidate_id is null
        order by delta_e_cie_2000(t.lab_l, t.lab_a, t.lab_b,
                                  c.lab_l, c.lab_a, c.lab_b) desc
        Limit 1 for update skip locked
    )
    RETURNING id into _tile_id;

    raise notice 'Tile %', _tile_id;
    return _tile_id;
end
$$;
select assign_next_candidate();

--does not commit changes until it's finished all assignments
create or replace function assign_all_candidates() RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    PARALLEL SAFE
AS
$$
declare
    counter integer := 0;
    last_id integer := 1;
begin
    while last_id is not null
        loop
            raise notice 'Counter %', counter;
            counter := counter + 1;
            last_id := assign_next_candidate();
            raise notice 'Updated %', last_id;
        end loop;
    return counter;
end
$$
;
```

I found this article really helpful: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

I've now got another issue which is that the queries run in parallel fine but they slow down a lot as they get further through the available rows. I think this is because the changes are not committed inside the loop in `assign_all_candidates()`, which means that the `SKIP LOCKED` queries are having to skip over a lot of candidates before finding one they can actually assign. I think I can get round that by breaking out of the loop every X records, committing those updates, and then re-calling `assign_all_candidates()`.

It's still much much faster than it was and seems robust.

#### Update:

As far as I can tell there is no way to commit within a `plpgsql` function (at least up to version 13). You can commit within anonymous code blocks, and [within procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html), but you can't have parallel procedures.

I've ended up creating a function that takes an array/series of IDs and updates each of them. I then call this function from multiple processes (via Python) so that the results are committed after each "block" is processed.

```py
queries = [
    "select assign_candidates(array[1,2,3])",
    "select assign_candidates(array[4,5,6])"
]
with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(do_query, queries)
```

Where the `assign_candidates` function looks something like

```sql
CRETE FUNCTION assign_candidates(_candidates integer[]) RETURNS integer
    PARALLEL SAFE
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _candidate_id int := 0;
BEGIN
    foreach _candidate_id in ARRAY _candidates
        LOOP
            perform assign_candidate(_candidate_id);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$;
```

This "split queries" approach scales fairly linearly as I process more rows unlike the previous approach that slowed down a lot as the number of rows grew (because it had to skip a lot of locked but not committed rows):
[image: graph showing that explicitly defining rows to update scales in a linear fashion compared to the original approach which is much slower for larger data sets]

It also scaled fairly well on more processors although doubling the number of processes does not halve the time (I guess because they are also trying to lock the same rows, and skipping over each other's locked rows):
[image: increasing the number of processes significantly reduces processing time]

For my use case the above approach reduced the processing time from nearly an hour to a few minutes, which was good enough.